# How to show $(f\circ\gamma)_{\star q}=\mathcal{J}(f\circ \gamma)_q $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ \gamma :R\rightarrow R^n$ and $f:R^n\rightarrow R$. If $q=0$; show that $$(f\circ\gamma)_{\star q}=\mathcal{J}(f\circ \gamma)_q $$

**My Attempt**:  We know that $$\mathcal{J}(f\circ \gamma)_q=(\mathcal{J}f)_{\gamma(q)}.(\mathcal{J}\gamma)_q.$$ 
Let $\gamma:R\to R^n$ be given by $\gamma(t)=q+tv$. Then, $ (f \circ \gamma)'(0)=v_q[f]$ and the Jacobian matrix $\mathcal{J}(f\circ \gamma) $ will be 1x1 because of $f\circ \gamma:R\to   R$.  $\mathcal{J}(f\circ \gamma)=[(f\circ \gamma)'(0)]_{1x1} $ which equals to $v_q[f].$

Is this correct ? How can I continue?

Or do we use $(f\circ \gamma)_{\star q}=f_{\star \gamma(q)}\circ \gamma_{\star q}$? (Where $\ell_{\star q}(v_q)=(v_q[f_1],v_q[f_2]...)_{\ell (q)}$ is derivative transformation and $\mathcal{J}$ is Jacobian matrix.)

is there anychance of quest. is not true?

Comment: Is $q=0\in \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^n$? Could you please explain what is $\star q$ in the l.h.s. of the relation to prove? In any case $\mathcal J (f\circ \gamma)= \frac{d (f\circ \gamma)}{dt}$ as you correctly noted, and this is equal to (with $\gamma(t)=(y_1(t),...,y_n(t)))$ the sum $\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}\frac{dy_i}{dt}$